# How to use percentage sign in annotate key

Tags: django, django-annotate

I'm trying to annotate a result column name with string that includes a percentage sign. This is the simplified code which can be run on any model basically:

```
from django.db.models import F

annotates = {'TEST %': F('id')}
SomeModel.objects.annotate(**annotates)[:1]
```

This produces error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` so I assumed Django is trying to do some formatting on that string and I tried putting double percentage sign `'TEST %%'` to escape it which does not raise an error but it returns double spaces as column name which is not what I need.

Same result in Django 2.2 and 3.1

Is this a Django bug or I'm missing some known escaping sequence here?

Comment: Please don't. How will you even access the annotation? Simply *render* it in the template with a percentage.

Comment: I would advise not to use spaces or percentage signs in the column name. This does not only makes querying fail, but would also make it hard to *access* the attribute later in the process.

Comment: It's not being rendered in template, it's a product statistics query which goes to excel. I did not have any issues with any of the characters when accessing column names so far, I don't see why would there be a problem with accessing them.

Comment: then still it is not a good idea, just render the column names with some logic, not with the attributes/keys of the dictionary. It is better to only use valid Python identifiers, so without spaces, percentages, etc.

Comment: the reason this does not work is because string formatting is applied for the *query*, but not for the attribute, so in the *query* it will use `TEST %`, but it will not do the same string interpolation for the *attribute*.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić Why not use the values() and have a key with `TEST %` in it with value from `id` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not use `%` sign in annotation with `F()` or `Cast()` in `Django`.**

Because they have used the old string formatting in their methods (i.e. `as_sql` method with percentage sign formatting) and your error comes from the line `return template % data, params` in these methods and since you've inserted another percentage sign in to the default template it couldn't render it's template. It is not related to your SQL query or your database, and the only thing responsible for this error is the way that they have used for formatting the string. One way to skip this error is to change the line

```
annotates = {'TEST %': F('id')}
```

to

```
annotates = {'TEST %%': F('id')}
```

which tells your `Python`'s interpreter to skip the percentage sign in formatting but note that in your annotation results you will have something like:

```
{...other fields..., 'TEST %%': some id}
```

Comment: So basically a Django bug :)